# Как установить timeout на запрос во Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, java, postgresql, vue.js

У меня есть Rest API с использованием Spring и JS библиотека на Vue Resource для обращения к этому Rest API.
В случае падения БД запрос к API висит в ожидании результата секунд по 10-15.
То есть речь не о самом vue-файле, а именно о запросе данных в этот template от API.

Сейчас 500-ый ответ в случае недоступности БД приходит через 10-15 секунд. Я хочу чтобы он приходил через 5. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну тут всё про100.

1. У вас есть доступ к исходникам Rest API? Можете ли вы изменить настройки Rest сервиса чтоб подключение к базе данных прерывалось после 5 секунд а не 15? Если да то [настраивайте подключение](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/restful-crud-api-using-postgresql-and-spring-boot-part-2/)

   spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=5000 # настройки тут
   spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5
   spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
2. если нет то читаем подробно [XMLHttpRequest.timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, даже не подумал о том, что можно установить лимит в application.properties. Спасибо, что направили в нужное русло :)